# plotting modified point and line plot - variability as "spike" plot in r

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

Before explaining details, here is my data:

```
set.seed (1234) 
datas <- data.frame (Indv = 1:20, Xvar = rnorm (20, 50, 10),
Yvar = rnorm (20, 30,5), Yvar1 = rnorm (20, 10, 2),
Yvar2 = rnorm (20, 5, 1), Yvar3 = rnorm (20, 100, 20),
Yvar4 = rnorm (20, 15, 3))
```

I want to prepare a graph (Metroglymph ) which is essentially point plot however points (of Xvar and Yvar) with spikes (lines) orignated from the point scaled to  rest of variables (Yvar1, Yvar2, Yvar3, Yvar4).
 Each spike are ordered and preferably color coded.

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(datas, aes(x=Xvar, y=Yvar)) +
    geom_point(shape=1, size = 10) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: this will take a bit of work to put together.  The easiest way is probably to combine an initial `plot()` call with `segments()` to add all the spikes, then `points()` to add the points.  It may take a tricky calculation to figure out where the edges of points start, for the purposes of adding segments that start from the edge (solid-color points [pch=16 or 23] would help for this -- you could plot them on top and obscure the parts of the segments underneath them -- but then you wouldn't see overlapping points properly)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one possible approach that may be helpful to you. It uses `stat_spoke()` from ggplot2. Each of your y-variables is mapped to the spoke radius in 4 separate calls to `stat_spoke`.

```
plot_1 = ggplot(datas, aes(x=Xvar, y=Yvar)) +
         stat_spoke(aes(angle=(1/8)*pi, radius=Yvar1), colour="#E41A1C",size=1) +
         stat_spoke(aes(angle=(3/8)*pi, radius=Yvar2), colour="#377EB8",size=1) +
         stat_spoke(aes(angle=(5/8)*pi, radius=Yvar3), colour="#4DAF4A",size=1) +
         stat_spoke(aes(angle=(7/8)*pi, radius=Yvar4), colour="#984EA3",size=1) +
         geom_point(shape=1, size = 10)

ggsave("plot_1.png", plot_1)
```

[image]

Depending on your data and specific needs, it may make sense to transform the variables so they fit better on the plot.

```
normalize = function(x) {
    new_x = (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)
    new_x = new_x + abs(min(new_x))
    return(new_x)
}

plot_2 = ggplot(datas, aes(x=Xvar, y=Yvar)) +
         stat_spoke(aes(angle=(1/8)*pi, radius=normalize(Yvar1)), colour="#E41A1C", size=1) +
         stat_spoke(aes(angle=(3/8)*pi, radius=normalize(Yvar2)), colour="#377EB8", size=1) +
         stat_spoke(aes(angle=(5/8)*pi, radius=normalize(Yvar3)), colour="#4DAF4A", size=1) +
         stat_spoke(aes(angle=(7/8)*pi, radius=normalize(Yvar4)), colour="#984EA3", size=1) +
         geom_point(shape=1, size = 10)

ggsave("plot_2.png", plot_2)
```

[image]

**Important caveat:** For the same spoke radius value, the magnitude of the plotted line will be greater if the line is more vertical, and less if the line is more horizontal. This is because the range of x is around twice the range of y for your data set. The plotted angles also become distorted as the x-to-y axis ratio changes. Adding `coord_equal(ratio=1)` solves this issue, but may introduce other problems.
[image]

### **Edit: Plotting without a loop**

This was fun and educational to figure out. Possibly it would have been more time-efficient to type the repetitive code! If anyone can offer advice to improve this code, please comment.

```
library(reshape2)

dat2 = melt(datas, id.vars=c("Indv", "Xvar", "Yvar"), 
            variable.name="spoke_var", value.name="spoke_value")

# Apply normalization in a loop. Can plyr do this more gracefully?.
for (var_name in levels(dat2$spoke_var)) {
    select_rows = dat2$spoke_var == var_name
    norm_dat = normalize(dat2[select_rows, "spoke_value"])
    dat2[select_rows, "spoke_value"] = norm_dat
}

# Pick an angle for each Yvar, then add angle column to dat2.
tmp = data.frame(spoke_var=unique(dat2$spoke_var))
tmp$spoke_angle = seq(from=pi/8, by=pi/4, length.out=nrow(tmp))
dat2 = merge(dat2, tmp)

plot_4 = ggplot(dat2, aes(x=Xvar, y=Yvar)) +
         stat_spoke(data=dat2, size=1,
                    aes(colour=spoke_var, angle=spoke_angle, radius=spoke_value)) +
         geom_point(data=datas, aes(x=Xvar, y=Yvar), shape=1, size=7) +
         coord_equal(ratio=1) +
         scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer ! As there might more than 4 variables is there a way to loop the process instead of writing stat_spoke (), 4 times

Comment: You can replace the `stat_spoke` arguments with a list of objects produced by that argument, so it is possible to loop it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is more manual approach:

```
set.seed (1234)
datas <- data.frame (Indv = 1:20, Xvar = rnorm (20, 50, 10),
Yvar = rnorm (20, 30,5), Yvar1 = rnorm (20, 10, 2),
Yvar2 = rnorm (20, 5, 1), Yvar3 = rnorm (20, 100, 20),
Yvar4 = rnorm (20, 15, 3))
datas$SYvar1 <- 2 + scale (datas$Yvar1)
datas$SYvar2 <- 2 +  scale (datas$Yvar2)
datas$SYvar3 <- 2 + scale (datas$Yvar3)
datas$SYvar4 <- 2 +  scale (datas$Yvar4)

    require(ggplot2)
    p <- ggplot(datas, aes(x=Xvar, y=Yvar)) +  
   geom_point(size = 10, pch = 19, col = "yellow2")
    p + geom_segment(aes(x = Xvar, y = Yvar, xend = Xvar + SYvar1, 
   yend = Yvar), col = "red4", size = 1) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = Xvar, y = Yvar, xend = Xvar, 
    yend = Yvar + SYvar2), col = "green4", size = 1) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = Xvar, y = Yvar, xend = Xvar-2.5,
    yend = Yvar + SYvar3), col = "darkblue", size = 1) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = Xvar, y = Yvar, xend = 
     Xvar - SYvar4, yend = Yvar ), col = "red", size = 1) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]